# vcruntime140_app.dll not included in the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64)?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, visual-c++

I have developed a GUI with QT and my release version needs vcruntime140_app.dll to run. I couldn't find this dll in my SysWOW64 folder, so I reinstalled the Microsoft Visual Stuio C++ 2017 Redistributables which (according to Microsoft) contain the vcruntime140_app.dll. The _app dlls are still not there after the reinstallation. The same dlls without _app are all there.

Comment: I am currently having this same issue, have you resolved it yourself or is it ongoing?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and found out that I used the wrong dll.

In my case I developed a desktop application but used the binaries in "winrt_...", where I should have used the binaries in "msvcXXX.." instead.

As I understand [winrt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html) is for developing windows store app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm this