# How do I connect to an sqlite database in C++ using visual studio 2017 on Windows?

Tags: c++, dll, sqlite, visual-studio-2017, visual-c++

I am fairly new to Windows development and C++. In trying to connect to an sqlite database, I've written the following snippet.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main()
{
    sqlite3* db;

    if (sqlite3_open(<path to db>, &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("ERROR: can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    else { printf("Connection Successful"); }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

I downloaded the Universal Windows Platform VSIX package from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, which included a sqlite3.lib file and a sqlite3.dll. In Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, I have included the sqlite3.lib file and directories and copied the sqlite3.dll to the project directory.

I should note the included sqlite3.lib is the x86 version. Trying to include the x64 version causes a build error with the '#include "sqlite3.h"' statement. I'd like to know why that's the case, but I can live with 32-bit for now.

Running the code as is yields the following error at runtime: "The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll was not found..."

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641364/vcruntime140-app-dll-not-included-in-the-microsoft-visual-c-2017-redistributab) suggests that the dll should have been included with the visual studio install. The mentioned dll file does exist in C:\Program Files (x86) in several places including the Microsoft SDKs folder, under which the .lib file resides. Why may it not be found?

Comment: Did you use the MSVS project wizard to create a Windows Store app (Universal App) or a standard Win32 Console App? You can't mix and match.

Comment: That may in fact be the issue, thanks. I'll check and see if any other downloads work.

Comment: @RichardCritten: You *can* use the overwhelming majority of the Universal Windows Platform API in a regular Desktop application. With a few exceptions, you *can* mix and match.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite will compile under msvc without a hassle. So you can directly include sqlite3.h and sqlite3.cpp  into your project in msvc and avoid using as dependency library.

Answer (score -2):

Download and copy the following folder to your Visual C++ solution folder.
https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/tree/master/sqlite3
The sqlite3 folder contains both x86 and x64 version of sqlite dll and lib.
You may upgrade to latest version of sqlite.dll.
Download and copy the following files to your Visual C++ project folder, add reference for them.
[https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/blob/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcychan/DNAssist/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.cpp)
[https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/blob/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcychan/DNAssist/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.h)

The following is the sample code to query the database.

```
#include "CppSQLite3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

CppSQLite3DB db;

bool GetDatabase(const string& dbPath)
{
    try {
        db.open(dbPath.c_str());
        return true;
    }
    catch (CppSQLite3Exception& e)
    {
        cout << _T("Cannot open database: ") << dbPath << _T("\n");
        return false;
    }
}

void IssueQuery(const string& querystring, const string& field1)
{
    try {
        CppSQLite3Query q = db.execQuery(querystring.c_str());
        while (!q.eof()) {
            CString temp2(q.fieldValue(field1.c_str()));
            TRACE(temp2 + _T("\n"));
            q.nextRow();
        }
    }
    catch (CppSQLite3Exception& e)
    {
        cout << _T("Cannot execute query: ") << querystring << _T("\n");
    }
}

void main()
{
    if(GetDatabase("C:\\test.sqlite"))
        IssueQuery("SELECT * FROM DUAL", "X");
}
```